# How to pass an unsigned long to a Linux shared library using P/Invoke

Tags: c#, mono, pinvoke

I am using C# in Mono and I'm trying to use pinvoke to call a Linux shared library.

The c# call is defined as:

```
   [DllImport("libaiousb")]
   extern static ulong AIOUSB_Init();
```

The Linux function is defined as follows:

```
  unsigned long AIOUSB_Init() {
       return(0);
  }
```

The compile command for the Linux code is:

```
gcc -ggdb -std=gnu99 -D_GNU_SOURCE -c -Wall -pthread -fPIC
      -I/usr/include/libusb-1.0  AIOUSB_Core.c -o AIOUSB_Core.dbg.o
```

I can call the function ok but the return result is bonkers.  It should be 0 but I'm getting some huge mangled number.

I've put printf's in the Linux code just before the function value is returned and it is correct.

One thing I have noticed that is a little weird is that the printf should occur before the function returns.  However, I see the function return to C# and then the c# prints the return result and finally the printf result is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://home.att.net/~jackklein/c/inttypes.html):

> An unsigned long can hold all the values between `0` and `ULONG_MAX` inclusive. `ULONG_MAX` must be at least `4294967295`. The long types must contain at least 32 bits to hold the required range of values.

For this reason a C `unsigned long` is usually translated to a .NET `UInt32`:

```
[DllImport("libaiousb")]
extern static uint AIOUSB_Init();
```

Comment: except if you run this on 64bit mono + linux, then the C unsigned long will be 64bits.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably running that on a system where C *unsigned long* is 32-bits. C# unsigned long is 64 bits. If you want to make sure the return value is a 64-bits unsigned long, include `stdint.h` and return an `uint64_t` from AIOUSB_Init().

Comment: You were so right!  Thank you very much!  You have no idea how long I beat my head on this.  I thought all the current pentium processors used 32 bit word size so an unsigned long should be 64 bits?

I will look for a secure way to use paypal to send you a small token of my appreciation!

Comment: An unsigned long is only 64-bits on 64-bit platforms (and under 64-bit operating systems), otherwise it's 32-bits.

Comment: For additional details, see my answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753413/parameters-passed-by-reference-come-back-garbage-using-p-invoke

Comment: FYI unsigned long is 64bits on 64bit linux, but 32bits on windows.