# P/Invoke g++ from mono in ubuntu OS

Tags: c#, c++, ubuntu, mono, pinvoke

Is it possible to invoke a g++ executable file's function from mono in Ubuntu? Note that both C++ and C# code compiled in Ubuntu Operation System.

C++ application source:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

static int32_t Sum(int32_t a, int32_t b){
    return a + b;
}
/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

C# mono application source:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MonoCsTest
{
 class MainClass
 {

  [DllImport("/home/.../MonoCsTest/bin/Debug/testcpp")]  
  public static extern Int32 Sum(Int32 a, Int32 b);

  public static void Main (string[] args)
  {
   Console.WriteLine (" 5 + 6 = " + Sum(5,6));
  }
 }
}
```

This throws `DllNotFoundException`

Comment: I've got an example with a shared library (.so) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753413/parameters-passed-by-reference-come-back-garbage-using-p-invoke/1753545#1753545). Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for that dtb, But my problem is `DllNotFoundException`!!!
I'm sure that file path is correct! I think it must be a stupid problem! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile the library as a shared library: a static library can't be loaded at runtime with P/Invoke.
The fact that you added a main() function suggests that you're compiling the code into an executable instead.
So the first thing for you is to learn how to compile a shared library, you can try something like:

```
gcc -shared -o libtestcpp.so testcpp.cpp
```

Then change the DllImport name to the path to the complete library name:

```
DllImport("/home/yourlogin/MonoCsTest/bin/Debug/libtestcpp.so")
```

The other mistake you made is not considering the C++ manadated name mangling: the simpler solution here is to export Sum() as a C function surrounding it with `extern "C" {}`.

To diagnose such mistakes it is often useful to enable the debug logging from mono using:

```
MONO_LOG_LEVEL="debug" MONO_LOG_MASK="dll" mono yourprog.exe
```

Comment: Name mangling generally causes an EntryPointNotFound exception, rather than a DllNotFound. As far as I'm aware, Mono can use exported symbols from both executables and shared libraries (I'm not entirely sure as to that, though).

Comment: Of course I know about the exception type (fwiw, I implemented this part of mono), that is why I first pointed out to him the reason he's getting the DllNotFound exception and later I pointed out the other issue he would have ran into as soon as he fixed the first. As for the part you are not sure about: your sentence is incorrect. Mono can load exported symbols from (correctly linked) shared libraries and global exported symbols from the *process* (note, not executable) that embeds mono when the special DllImport name "__Internal" is used. There is a semi-exception: PIE executables.

Comment: But PIE executables are basically shared libs and I didn't want to bring them out because people are already confused enough:)

Answer (score 0):

As long as a symbol is exported and Mono can understand the parameters (enough to marshal data to/from them), then yes, you can do this. I think the Mono pages on PInvoke actually mention that you can invoke functions exported by both libraries and executables, including an executable that embeds Mono.

You need to verify that the symbol is indeed being exported, and more importantly, that it is not mangled or you match that in the C# side. That's the spot I've had the most stupid problems with.

Comment: The problem is `DllNotFoundException`! Is it because of unmatchable data types? I don't think! :)

Comment: From the error, I'm gonna guess it just can't find the library (or that's the best place to start). Have you checked the paths, made sure the names are right, all that?

Comment: Yes, I check them! I also check file permission. :'(

Comment: Try placing the C++ library or executable in the same directory as the Mono executable and running it with that as the working directory. This page may be able to help more, it's Mono's interop information: http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries