# C++ function exported in dll and loaded from C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllimport

I have in C++:

> void __declspec(dllexport) foo(HWND wnd)

And in C#

> ```
> [DllImport("MyDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
> public static extern void foo(IntPtr wnd);
> ```

When I'm trying to call it I have this error - Additional information: Unable to find an entry point named 'foo' in DLL. I tried to inspect the dll and I have the function with the fallowing definition:

Undecorated C++ Function:
void **cdecl foo(struct HWND** *)

I searched on several forums and is seems that this is the right way to do this... Do you know why I have this run time error?

Comment: Check out my Question, Maybe help!

http://stackoverflow.com/q/4108181/375958

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to disable C++ name mangling.  Declare your native function like this:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void foo(HWND wnd)
```

You can use the dumpbin.exe utility to see DLL exports as well.

Comment: It works, thank you! I will accept the answer in 11 minutes:P

Comment: Glad to help.  And yes, if you don't have the source things get a bit more painful, but since you do I wouldn't worry about that for now.  I would however look up "C++ name mangling" just so you know what is actually going on here.  I would un-delete your answer Adam as you are right on in the case where editing the source is not an option.